# Do you always pronounce ST as SHT?

Tags: pronunciation

If you have a word like 'Strasse' and it forms part of a street name for example, then I would assume that you still pronounce the word as though it were by itself.

But are there examples of when you wouldn't pronounce ST as SHT?

Comment: Am be*st*en frag*st* Du jemanden, der das *Sht*udiert hat. I don't know the underlying rule...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In standard German pronunciation, this happens when (and only when) *st* is the first part of a syllable.

> Straße -- Stra·ße -- /ˈʃt/
>
> verstehen -- ver·ste·hen -- /ˈʃt/
>
> Kasten -- kas·ten -- /st/
>
> bester -- bes·ter -- /st/
>
> fast -- fast -- /st/

I'll add that there are a few loan words that *can* be pronounced without the SH sound, e.g. *Star*, *Stimulus*, *Stracciatella*, *Spam*, *Stil*. See the comments for some discussion on the subject.

Comment: +1; correct for standard German.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Right, I'll add that disclaimer :)

Comment: I think every 's' in first syllable which is followed by 't' or 'p', is pronounced /ˈʃ/.

Comment: @Gigili It doesn't matter which syllable it happens in, as long as it's the onset.

Comment: @Tim: When it happens in first syllable then 'st' or 'sp' is the first part of a syllable then it's surely pronounced /ʃ/ .. even if it is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: Does the same hold true for SP = SHP then? Sorry, it's not completely clear

Comment: @adolf: Yes, as Gigili said, it's the same rule with _sp_.

Comment: Some northern Germans, especially in Hamburg, do what is called "Stolpern übern spitzen Stein", pronounced without /ʃ/. My grandfather (originally form Soltau) and my uncle used to talk that way. My mother consciously changed to the standard way when she was a teenager in the 1950s.

Comment: Loanwords like stabil, Stracciatella or Stimulus pronounced WITHOUT the sch- sound quite overblown.

Comment: Well, how do you know it is the first part of a syllable?

Comment: @Debilski: It comes naturally :) How to divide a word into syllables should probably be a new question (if it's on-topic here).

Comment: @bot47 is right here, some loanwords are correctly pronounced with *sh* sound, but *may* be also pronounced without. Stracciatella is correctly pronounced Italian, but in German, it's also typically pronounced with *sh* (and *tz* instead of the Italian *cc*). *Star*, on the other hand, is mostly pronounced without *sh*.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Star SHOULD be pronounced without Sch- to avoid confusion with the german translation of "starling"

Comment: @bot47: Duden provides both pronounciations though, with the English pronounciation coming first (which is different from the Latin loanwords, which either have the *sh* version first or even as the only one). A note to learners: The German word Star (with two different meanings: a bird and an eye disease) are of course always pronounced with *sh*, as bot47 already implied :)

Comment: @Oregon Stracciatella is practically always pronounced Italian in Austria.

Comment: @thei: I just tested a few pronounciation examples for the word in both meanings (the ice-cream and the soup - didn't find one for the cheese (; ), and they were all like Italian. However, I never heard it pronounced that way here in the North :)

Answer (score 9):

Many people tend to pronounce Latin-derived words with sharp s, like Strategie, though it is still correct to pronounce it as *sht*. However, there are also many dialects, especially in Northern Germany, that *always* prounounce it as *st*, not *sht*.

On the other hand, I could think of a different case: *Martinstrasse* vs. *Martinstraße* (*Martins-Trasse* vs. *Martin-Straße*). Of course, in the first case, it's no longer *Straße* ;)

Comment: As much as the *Hamburger* pronounce *st* always sharp many dialects always pronounce the *st* like *sht*.

Comment: @Takkat: Which makes matters even more complicated for learners ;)

Comment: @Takkat: And adds a reason to add the Hamburger slang hint to the answer.

Comment: And southern Germans might even say "beshten". It's part of the "Lautverschiebung", which is strongest in the south.