# I have a problem with "st"

Tags: pronunciation

I have a problem about the pronunciation of "st". I read that it is pronounced "sht" when it appears in the first syllable but I saw some words when it is pronounced "sht" in the middle. for example: Verstehen, Einstein.
I want to ask if those words are just exceptions ?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/679/do-you-always-pronounce-st-as-sht/

Comment: So I've been pronouncing Einstein wrong all this time? Oh dear.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, the rule you read was incomplete. It's pronounced as *sht* (from now on /ʃt/) if the cluster is at the start of a syllable. Some examples:

- [entstehen](http://www.forvo.com/word/entstehen/#de)
- [Strom](http://www.forvo.com/word/strom/#de)
- [still](http://www.forvo.com/word/still/#de)

Just like any other rule in the German language, there are exceptions. I picked `still` previously on purpose to show that orthography is not always to be trusted. Mostly because of foreign words. Something that comes immediately to mind is the word

- [Stil](http://www.forvo.com/word/stil/#de)

As you can hear from the recording, the first sound wasn't /ʃt/, but a simple /st/.

If separating words into syllables isn't exactly intuitive, and you're dealing with a compound word, try separating the root words.

> Haltestelle - halte/stelle

If you're dealing with prefixes eliminate them.

> bestrafen - be/strafen

Lastly, if you have the chance, check websites like [forvo](http://forvo.com).

Comment: and then there are schwaben, who use `sht` everywhere :(

Comment: @BЈовић And that's how a Swabian identifies the Reingeschmeckte because it is not true ;)

Comment: @BЈовић: Des schdimmd fei gar net!

Comment: Ich kenne "Stil" in beiden Aussprachen, und hier in Hessen vorzugsweise mit /ʃt/, auch wenn der Sprecher Hochdeutsch spricht. Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stil) kennt ebenfalls beide Aussprachen.

Answer (score 6):

No, these words are not exceptions. The phenomenon you are observing is quite common. The rule that you are quoting holds also when words are composed or used with a prefix: ver-stehen (prefix "ver", base word "stehen"), Ein-stein (it's a name anyway, but same principle), aus-steigen, Fahr-stuhl (composition of "fahren" and "Stuhl") and so on.

Answer (score 2):

At first: there are some German dialects (in the hanseatic region), where st and sp is *not* pronounced sht and shp respectively but at face value. I agree with clinch, that in most cases and most regions, it *is* pronounced sht and shp. Unfortunately there are exceptions, especially at the end of a word (Last, Lust, Mast, fast, List), if the s is doubled to shorten the preceeding vowel (frisst) and of course, where a composite word was formed and the word border runs between s and t like Mus-topf (literally a jar holding purée, used in negative context like in the phrase "aus dem Mustopf kommen" meaning "being narrow-minded, limited").

Comment: You might still want to explain what a Mustopf is. I think it's a rare and old word that is difficult to understand for German non-natives.

Comment: "*aus dem Mustopf kommen*": a saying that could be loosely translated to "*being clueless / disoriented/ dull-witted*".. FYI: in southern German dialects *all* `st` get pronounced `scht`. e.g "du bist" -> *"du bischt"*. Quite a difference in dialects :)

Comment: Make that _some_ Southern German dialects, please.